# Django 1.10 RequestContext processors not working

Tags: python, django

After updating to django 1.10, processors stop working.

This menu context for many views:

```
def menu_category(request):
    category_parent = Category.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True, is_active=True).order_by('mass')
    category_child = Category.objects.filter(parent__isnull=False, is_active=True).order_by('mass')
    return {'category_parent': category_parent, 'category_child': category_child}
```

This view for django 1.9 (in django 1.10 processors=[menu_category] empty context):

```
def news_main(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(
        Q(date_completion__gt=timezone.now()) | Q(date_completion=None),
        date_published__lte=timezone.now(),
        is_active=True).order_by('-date_published')
    return render_to_response('news/news_main.html',
    {'posts': posts},
    RequestContext(request, processors=[menu_category]))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should never have been passing a RequestContext to `render_to_response`, and Django 1.10 has made that an error. Instead use the `render` shortcut:

```
return render(request, 'news/news_main.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Note that whenever you upgrade a version you should always make sure to read the release notes; in this case the change is noted under [Features removed in 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#features-removed-in-1-10).

Comment: How, then, can I add context menu_category in template?

Comment: It is applied automatically, as long as it is listed in the `context_processors` option of the TEMPLATES setting.